# XERO API Returns HTTP 503 when sending multiple invoices in one requests

Tags: xero-api, http-status-code-503, akamai

One of my clients gets HTTP 503 every time they try to send multiple invoices in one request.
Is anyone else having this issue?

I am using CURL to send a request to XERO, is this message from XERO?

Below is the CURL command

curl.exe -X POST "https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices" -d "@C:\Temp\RES1XEROInvoicesPOSTDATA.xml" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFDQUY4RTY2NzcyRDZEQzAyOEQ2NzI2RkQwMjYxNTgxNTcwRUZDMTkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJISy1Pxxxx"  -H "Accept: application/xml"  -H "Xero-tenant-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx" -D "C:\Temp\RES1RespHeader.txt" > response.txt  -v -o "C:\Temp\RES1RespBody.txt"

[Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu3aE.png)
[Response Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CozOJ.png)

Thanks,
Komal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added the curl command  that I m running. Thanks